# How to group some keys of dictionary to nested key?

Tags: python

I have a dictionaries of list

```
[{
'LoanID' : 001,
'Applicant_Income.1' : 5000,
'Applicant_Occupation.1' : "Manager",
'Applicant_Income.2' : 3000,
'Applicant_Occupation.2' : "Accountant",
'LoanAmount' : 10000
},
{
'LoanID' : 002,
'Applicant_Income.1' : 6000,
'Applicant_Occupation.1' : "Senior Manager",
'Applicant_Income.2' : 2000,
'Applicant_Occupation.2' : "Services",
'LoanAmount' : 8000
}]
```

I need to create a new key 'Applicant' and move 'Applicant_Income' and 'Applicant_Occupation' inside that, result each dict in list looks like

```
{
'LoanID' : 001,
'Applicant' : [
     { 
       'Applicant_Income' : 5000,
       'Applicant_Occupation' : "Manager"
     }'
     {
       'Applicant_Income' : 3000,
       'Applicant_Occupation' : "Accountant"
     }]
'LoanAmount' : 10000
},
{
'LoanID' : 002,
'Applicant' : [
     { 
       'Applicant_Income' : 6000,
       'Applicant_Occupation' : "Senior Manager"
     }'
     {
       'Applicant_Income' : 2000,
       'Applicant_Occupation' : "Services"
     }]
'LoanAmount' : 8000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (`info` is the list you defined above):

```
for d in range(len(info)):
    info[d]['Applicant'] = [{'Applicant_Income.1': info[d]['Applicant_Income.1'], 'Applicant_Occupation.1': info[d]['Applicant_Occupation.1']}, {'Applicant_Income.2': info[d]['Applicant_Income.2'], 'Applicant_Occupation.2': info[d]['Applicant_Occupation.2']}]
    del info[d]['Applicant_Income.1']
    del info[d]['Applicant_Occupation.1']
    del info[d]['Applicant_Income.2']
    del info[d]['Applicant_Occupation.2']
```

Output:

```
[{'LoanID': '002',
  'LoanAmount': 10000,
  'Applicant': [{'Applicant_Income.1': 5000,
    'Applicant_Occupation.1': 'Manager'},
   {'Applicant_Income.2': 3000, 'Applicant_Occupation.2': 'Accountant'}]},
 {'LoanID': '002',
  'LoanAmount': 8000,
  'Applicant': [{'Applicant_Income.1': 6000,
    'Applicant_Occupation.1': 'Senior Manager'},
   {'Applicant_Income.2': 2000, 'Applicant_Occupation.2': 'Services'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer only works if the number of values for income and occupation is fixed to two.

Here is a more dynamic solution: 
**orgList** is the list you define above 
**finalList** is the list you want

```
def getApplicant(entry):
    tempAppList = []
    for key in [key for key in entry if 'Applicant_Income' in key]:
        tempAppDict = {}
        tempAppDict['Applicant_Income'] = entry[key]
        tempAppDict['Applicant_Occupation'] = entry[key.replace('Income', 'Occupation')]
        tempAppList.append(tempAppDict)
    
    return tempAppList

finalList = []

for entry in orgList:
    tempDict = {}
    tempDict['LoanID'] = entry['LoanID']
    tempDict['Applicant'] = getApplicant(entry)
    tempDict['LoanAmount'] = entry['LoanAmount']
    
    finalList.append(tempDict)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "LoanID": "001",
        "Applicant": [
            {
                "Applicant_Income": 5000,
                "Applicant_Occupation": "Manager"
            },
            {
                "Applicant_Income": 3000,
                "Applicant_Occupation": "Accountant"
            }
        ],
        "LoanAmount": 10000
    },
    {
        "LoanID": "002",
        "Applicant": [
            {
                "Applicant_Income": 6000,
                "Applicant_Occupation": "Senior Manager"
            },
            {
                "Applicant_Income": 2000,
                "Applicant_Occupation": "Services"
            }
        ],
        "LoanAmount": 8000
    }
]
```

Note: Leading zeros are not allowed on integers (like you have on LoadId). So you need to use a string for that

Comment: 1. `Applicant_Occupation` values should be strings like `"Manager"`, `"Accountant"`, etc. Instead, you've got the salary. 2. The first character of `'income'` and `'occupation'` should be uppercase. This is why you get the salary twice instead of the job. `'Hello'.replace('hello', 'world')` is still just `'Hello'` because the replacement never occurs. So it's the same key of entry. 3. In the for-loop in `getApplicant`, the `key, value in entry.items()` could be just `key in entry` since you never use the `value`. Or use `value` for the salary entry.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. Guess that was a bit of a hasty attempt by me. Didn't pay enough attention to the output. Both point 1 & 2 is actually due to the lowercase issue you mentioned. In regards to point 3 you made that is not true. You have to use key, value. If you only use one argument it will be value and not key

Comment: [Iterating over dictionaries gives the keys](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not the values. _"Performing `list(d)` on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in insertion order"_. If `d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}` then `list(d)` is `['key1', 'key2']` and `for x in d: print(x)` prints the keys.

Comment: Ok you are right I have not read your initinal response correctly.  It works if I drop the .items() part. With it I have to keep both key and value. But I agree that makes the code unnecessary  complicated so I will change it. Thanks for helping me to create a better (and working) solution :)